# Windows AD CA Cert template access

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate-authority

I have Windows Server 2102 R2 and our AD team created a certificate template and assigned the permissions of enroll and read to a group my server is included it. 
 However my machine is not listing the template as an option.

When I run certutil -Template It shows the permissions on the template properly, my machine and group are listed with enroll and read.

However, when I run certutil -ADTemplate the template shows as access denied. I am running this command from the machine with the assigned permissions.

Anybody have any ideas on what could be stopping my machine from using the template or other commands I can try to get a specific error?

To enroll the certificate I opened the MMC and added the certificate plugin.  I then chose computer(local).  I went to all tasks and request new certificate.  In the wizard I chose active directory enrollment policy and the template was not one of the options so I checked show all and it shows the template I was trying for then however showing not available.

Comment: Can you provide steps you are using to enroll certificate?

Comment: @Crypt32 updated the question to reflect enrollment process.